# What is the proper way to do an in-place upgrade of a Windows Parity Storage Space?

Tags: windows-10, storage-spaces

I currently have a 3-drive parity storage space on Windows 10, which provides 16TB of storage across three 8TB drives.

I wish to upgrade this to use three larger drives for more space.  Is there a way to do this in-place?  In other words, replace the drives one at a time, rebuilding the array each time, and then upgrade the total size of the volume?  If so, what is the proper way to do this, and are there any precautions I should take?

Comment: `are there any precautions I should take?` backup backup backup

Comment: You are aware the time required to rebuild that size of array is significant? Yes; There is an option to extend the size of your parity drive within the properties of the Storage Space itself.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I assume it will take at minimum a day per drive.